# how to combine post and get method with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two jquery function get and post.

I retrieve data from get method first and post my data with post method.

I want to know **how to combine this two function**.

POST Method

```
var url = '/api/sample?id=' + id ;
AJAXnotification("Saving...", 'info');
$.post( url , form)
.done(function(){
    AJAXnotification("Saved", 'success', 5000); 
})
.fail(function() {
    AJAXnotification("Cannot save", 'error');
});
```

GET Method

AJAXnotification("Loading...", 'info');

```
var fail_callback = function() {
    AJAXnotification("Cannot load ", 'error');
}

$.get('/api/samples', {
    'id'      : id,
    'merge'   : 'departures',
    'departures.from_date': from_date,
    'departures.to_date'  : to_date
}).done(function( tours ){
    AJAXnotification(" loaded", 'success', 5000);
});
```

Comment: Combine how? Call post after get finishes?

Comment: I just want one request to server

Comment: Since that's not possible, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: This looks like the [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - explain what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it

Comment: If you want a single call to server then you need to make a different api on the server which performs both the operations.If you are doing some manipulation on client side before posting, your objective is not possible. You need to create a process flow diagram about your requirement. That will help you design solution in an effective manner.In this question the requirement and process flow both are conflicting. So providing a technical solution to this is not feasible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just embedding the `$.post` inside the `.done` function of your `$.get` will make the `$.post` fire after the `$.get` returns, and you'll be able to access all of the returned data:

```
$.get('/api/samples', {
    'id'      : id,
    'merge'   : 'departures',
    'departures.from_date': from_date,
    'departures.to_date'  : to_date
}).done(function( tours ){
    AJAXnotification(" loaded", 'success', 5000);

    var url = '/api/sample?id=' + id ;
    AJAXnotification("Saving...", 'info');
    $.post( url , form)
    .done(function(){
        AJAXnotification("Saved", 'success', 5000); 
    })
    .fail(function() {
        AJAXnotification("Cannot save", 'error');
    });
});
```

Comment: i want request 1 time bro

Comment: Your `$.get` goes to `/api/samples` but your `$.post` goes to `/api/sample?id=n` - how exactly do you plan to send 1 request to 2 different places?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way :

```
    <form id="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="nameGet" id="nameGet" /> 
        <input type="text" name="namePost" id="namePost" /> 
        <input onclick="submitGetPostForm();" type="button" name="submitBtm" id="submitBtm" value="submit" /> 
    </form>

    <script>

        function submitGetPostForm()
        {
            nameGet=$('#nameGet').val();
            namePost=$('#namePost').val();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "testPage.php?nameGet="+nameGet,
                    type: "post",               
                    data: {namePost:namePost},
                    success: function(response_msg){                        

                        response_msg=$.trim(response_msg);
                        alert(response_msg);        

                    },
                    error:function(){                   

                        alert("Failure, some problem");                                             
                    }
            });                 
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: What if someone presses [Return] in the second textbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your POST operation to the .done callback of the GET operation.

```
$.get('/api/samples', {
    ...
 }).done(function( tours ){
   $.post( url , form)
      .done(function(){
          ...
        })
      .fail(function() {
         ...
       });
 });
```